# Simple glossy balls in Blender internal renderer

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to make a bunch of balls bouncing around, and I want them to look really glossy and plastic/toy-like, using **Blender Render**.

I made a plane emitting light above the balls, to make a shiny rectangle on all balls, which looks pretty good, but the balls are all reflecting each other, so it looks kind of stupid like the image below.

How can I make balls, and other plastic objects that look glossy without making them reflect each other and still look shiny/glossy?

I guess I would need to fake reflections somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should simply find a better balance between the "mirror" and the "specular" function of the material, as picture 1.

[image]

If you really want to fake the reflections, you could render the previous scene, then render only balls, lights and white reflective plane over a transparent background, unchecking the "traceable" option of the material (this will delete the cross reflection between balls, but shadows also will disappear); then composite the two images: floor and shadows from the first render, balls with no cross-reflections from the second (you will miss the shadows of balls over others balls).
This method works also for animation movies.
[image]